# How to split complex fractions like $\frac{e^{-as}}{s(1-e^{-as})}$ using partial fraction technique?

Tags: partial-fractions

$$\frac{e^{-as}}{s(1-e^{-as})}=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{1-e^{-as}}$$

Multiply the whole thing by $s(1-e^{-as})$
$$e^{-as}=A(1-e^{-as})+Bs$$

I distribute and try to find A and B by matching coefficients.

I get $A=1, -1$ and $B=0$. Now what?

Turns out by a little trial and error, I get:
$$-\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s(1-e^{-as})}$$

Comment: Partial fractions is a decomposition theorem for _rational functions_ (quotients of polynomials), not for general expressions involving quotients. Particularly, there's no guarantee that your particular function can be decomposed in the form of the first line, and your calculation shows that no values of $A$ and $B$ make the first line true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and substract $1$ upstairs to have:

$$\frac{e^{as}}{s (1-e^{as})} =  \frac{1  - 1 +e^{as}}{s (1-e^{as})} = -\frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s (1-e^{as})}$$

Comment: Note that the point of this was the cancellation $\frac{-1+e^{as}}{1-e^{as}}=-1$.